# VBA Write a loop that creates Random Numbers converts them to ASCII, and concatenates it to create an eight character key

Tags: vba

I'm able to create the random number between 33 and 126  and convert it to its corresponding character/ASCII code but I cannot repeat these steps to generate an eight character key, i know i need some sort of a loop.
 This is what i have done so far:

```
    RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next()
    RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(33, 126)
    Key.Text = RandomNumber
    Key2.Text = Chr(Int(Key.Text))
End Sub



Function Random()
    Dim arr(7) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    i = 1
    Do
        RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next()

        RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(33, 126)
        RandomNumber(i) = RandomNumber(i) + RandomNumber(i - 1)
        i = i + 1

    Loop Until i = 8

    Return RandomNumber
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Not really understanding your code and there are a couple problems there. A VBA function does not use a `return` statement -- you should set the function name to the return value `Random = RandomNumber`. I'm thinking you're trying to concatenate the numbers using `+`, but that's other languages. Use the ampersand `&` to concatenate strings. Also, look to use the [`STR`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/str.php) function to convert from a number to a string.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks a lot, Peter, very much appreciated.